# cancel-able measurement algorithm

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

I'm developing a `Winform` application for doing a measurement. The measurement involves external hardware like a robot, power supply, etc.

Since the measurement itself is long running (about 20 minutes), it will run in a backgroundworker.

The main problem for me is how to design the measurement cancle-able. The user should be able to cancel the measurement if he does something wrong for example. But the measurement should not be canceled everywhere - for example it's not allowed to cancel while performing `IO`-communication. Additionally there should be a save `shutdown` if the user cancelled.

The problem is, I don't want to pollute the business logic (measurement) with cancel related code.

What's a good approach for this?

I've done a similar logic in `python`. There I implemented the measurement as a state machine (`FSM`). Each state transition was a cancellation point. If the user cancelled while a state was running, the state machine jumped to a `finish` state, where the safe shutdown happened.

Comment: You can still make yourself a state machine or add a bool flag that your background code checks at times when it can abort execution

Comment: And also see [the documentation about cancelling managed threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd997364.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decide to use a BackgroundWorker (as you suggest), you should be able to use the [CancellationPending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx) property to determine if the user is trying to cancel the action.  You can check this as you run through the states of your state machine.  Psuedo code might look something like:

```cs
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
  // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
  var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

  // run the state machine
  var machine = new Machine();
  while (!machine.isComplete()) {
     if (worker.CancellationPending) {
       machine.safeFinish();
     } else {
       machine.executeNextState();
     }
  }

  // Assign the result of the computation 
  e.Result = machine.result();
}
```